# how to add a .txt file into html

Tags: html, web

So i am making a website but I do not know how to add a file.txt into my site. Where would I add it in this code?

```
  <h1 align=Center>title bla bla bla</h1>
  <p align=Center>N - Z</p>
  <div class="topnav">
  <div><p txt=file.txt></p></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<embed src="path.txt">
```